C++ constructor "alias" to pass a class-member as argument
I have a (template) class with a constructor that takes two parameters:
template <typename T>
struct Reg {
    T val;

    Reg(std::string name, ComplexObject &obj) { ... }
};

and I want to use it as the type for members in a different class, but with a member of that class always passed as the second argument (in the default member initializers):
struct Top {
    ComplexObject obj;

    // Now instead of passing "obj" every time like this:
    Reg<int> a{"a", obj};
    // I want to do it like this, where "obj" is implicitly passed:
    RegAlias<int> b{"b"};

    Top(ComplexObject obj) : obj(obj) {}
};

How can i define RegAlias<T> so I can use it like in the above code snippet?
I want to define a lot of members like b, so I don't want to type it out everytime, as it's always the same argument.
Something like a nested class doesn't work, as the nested class can't access members of the surrounding class.  Macros/factory functions also don't work as they can't directly be used for class members.
Is there a way to make this work?

Nope.  There's no way to do that.  Now, if EVERY invocation of Reg will be inside a class that contains an obj member, you may be able to do something like Reg<int,Top> but you'd still have to pass this.  There's no magic access to outer members.

This seems to be an "XY" problem (you want to do "X", think that doing "Y" will achieve "X", and then ask how to do "Y" - and "Y" turns out to be impossible in rules of the language).   In short, as also noted by Tim Roberts, I believe there is no solution to your question as asked.
